# writing binary data (std::string) to an std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, binary, iostream

I have an `std::string` object containing binary data which I need to write to a file. Can `ofstream f("name"); f << s;` be problematic in any way? I need to read the data back exactly as it was originally.

I can of course use `fwrite(s.c_str(), s.size(), 1, filep)`, are there any pros / cons to either method?

Comment: Whilst what you're doing is perfectly valid (don't forget to open the `ofstream` in binary mode.. whether your data is binary or not, frankly) I would have used `vector<char>` for the added feel-good factor. Any reason you didn't?

Comment: @Tomalak: I am using a set of transformer classes that accept and return `string`. `string` seemed a convenient interface for manipulating buffers, like appending/substituting into another content etc. I though at one point to define a `binaryString` as `basic_string<unsigned char>`, but it required too much time for refactoring which I didn't have at that time. But could I use the `<<` operator with `vector<char>`?

Comment: Nope. But then again I'd not want to use `<<` for binary data anyway, as my brain reads it as "formatted output" which is not what you're doing. Again, it's perfectly valid, but I just would not confuse my brain like that. :) The native appending is certainly useful, though.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal et. al...may I draw your attention to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230786/inserters-and-extractors-reading-writing-binary-data-vs-text/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be ok as long as you open the ofstream for binary access.

```
ofstream f("name", ios::binary | ios::out); 
f << s;
```

Don't forget to open your file in binary mode when reading the data back in as well.